# How to use the same class accross multiple threads and return a variable

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, loops, .net-3.5

My apologies in advance if this has already been answered, but every search I have done does not come close to what I need.  Also, this is all pseudo code.

Here is the situation:  I created a form (targeting DOT NET 3.5) that does a loop on a gridview  recreating a class and runs the code. After the code runs, there is a local variable on the class that gets updated and allows me to use it and the process repeats. Something like this:

```
For x as Integer = 0 to Me.txtTextBox.Lines.Count - 1 'Can be in the hundreds
Dim objMyClass as MyClass = New MyClass(Me.DatagridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value)
if objMyClass.Start() = True then
'Do my thing with objMyClass.LocalLongVariable
End If
Next
```

This works just fine, but takes literally days to complete. The last time I ran this it took like 6 days, 7 hours and 40 something minutes to complete and barely bumped the CPU usage.

So, now I want to use MulitThreading to run several of these instances at the same time.  I have not been able to get this to work.  Everything I try returns different values every time I run it (and it should not).  I believe that the threads are accessing the local variable across other threads and are incrementing at will.  And SyncLock locks up the entire program.  I have also tried adding a custom event that fires when the process is completed and executes a delegate on the Main form, but that has not worked either.

Now, my question is simple:  How can I run multiple threads using the same base class (passing a unique string variable) and have the local class variable produce the correct results back to the UI? (And, from what I have been reading, the BackgroundWorker class in not suitable for this many threads (like hundreds); correct me if I read it incorrectly please)

I am looking for something like:

```
Dim thrd(Me.txtTextBox.Lines.Count) as Thread
Dim objMyClass(Me.txtTextBox.Lines.Count) as MyClass
For x as Integer = 0 to Me.txtTextBox.Lines.Count - 1
thrd(x) = new Thread (Sub() 
                       objMyClass(x) = New MyClass(Me.GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
                       If objMyClass.Start() = True Then
                       'Do my stuff here (maybe call a delegate??)
                       End If
                       End)
thrd(x).IsBackground = True
thrd(x).Start()
Next
```

Any help/advice on how to proceed will be greatly appreciated.  And, if you know of any examples of your suggestion, please post the code/link.

Comment: It appears I am a better idiot than a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was, in fact, Synclock.  My issue was that I was locking the wrong object, objMyClass, instead of the current Me AND I was failing to use Monitor.PulseAll().  Also, I switched to using the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf objMyClass, args) and also used SyncLock on my custom event raised when the thread completes.  It's a whole lot easier!!  Thanks!!